# How to replicate text on many spans

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml

What you type inside the input box should be replicated below, on each span.

I can do this with de js code below, but to do so I need to make the same code over and over again for each span that needs to be completed. I've tried using same class "one" on every span, but only works on the first span. I have to create a new class for every span and some code for each one of those spans.

I want to know a way to replicate the same text in many many spans without so much code. How?

```js
var rep = document.getElementById('A');
    rep.addEventListener('input', function() {
        var result = document.querySelector('span.one');
        result.innerHTML = this.value;
    });
    
    var rep = document.getElementById('A');
    rep.addEventListener('input', function() {
        var result = document.querySelector('span.two');
        result.innerHTML = this.value;
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="A">
<p>One: <span class="one"></span></p>
<p>Two: <span class="two"></span></p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `querySelectorAll` to select all the elements of same css selector. Please use following code:

Please use [this link to study more about querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

```js
var rep = document.getElementById('A');
    rep.addEventListener('input', function() {
        var result = document.querySelectorAll('span');
        for(const res of result) {
          res.innerHTML = this.value;
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="A">
<p>One: <span class="one"></span></p>
<p>Two: <span class="two"></span></p>
```